# Use equational proofs to solve the problem

Tags: logic

Use equational proof to solve the problem.

> $ \vdash A \lor (B \rightarrow A) \equiv B \rightarrow A $

These are the axioms and theorems.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use: $B\rightarrow A\equiv\lnot B\lor A$

Comment: Did you just want to share this with us or is there a question somewhere in here?

Comment: Prove this $ \vdash A \lor (B \rightarrow A) \equiv B \rightarrow A $ That's the question.

Comment: @b00nheT I used it but could't continue.

Comment: $ A \lor (B \rightarrow A) = A \lor (\lnot B\lor A)= (\lnot B\lor A)\lor A= \lnot B\lor (A\lor A)=\lnot B\lor A = B \rightarrow A$

Comment: @JoseAntonio Can you help me with this one ? $ A \lor A \lor A \vdash B \rightarrow A $